# Framework de UI que não tenha conflito com Angular 2+?

Tags: angular

Estou utilizando o Angular 4, gostando muito, mas vi que a documentação do Angular sugere que se utilize CSS por componentes, correto? Achei uma prática meio desconfortável e estou preferindo utilizar ele por style, normalmente.

No entanto, vejo que ele entra em conflito com JQuery e algum JavaScript, onde alguns componentes, como por exemplo o navbar do Bootstrap e os forms do Materialize param de funcionar corretamente. Enfim, teria alguma solução para isso, ou realmente devo utilizar algum Framework sem JavaScript ou baseado em componentes ?

Comment: Pode linkar a referência da documentação que diz do CSS por componentes?

Comment: Ideal realmente não é misturar Angular com jQuery e sim usar os frameworks que possuem as diretivas do Angular, tais como [Angular Material](https://material.angularjs.org/latest/), [Bootstrap](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/home), etc.

Comment: Quando se trata de framework modularizado (angular), é bom usar frameworks de UI compatíveis e adaptáveis a eles, geralmente são oficiais como o https://material.angular.io/ para angular-2

Comment: @LucasCosta, Material AngularJS é compativel somente com AngularJS 1.x

Comment: Sim @FelipeDuarte, coloquei como comentário porque não domino Angular 4 para postar uma resposta, mas pra exemplificar as frameworks que existem.